# Is it safe to assign reference variable,which is of method level to Class level reference variable?

Tags: java, member-functions

If i have following code for a Java program

```
class Dotcom{
    private int positions[];// position is reference variable at class level
    //some other instance variables
    // suppose here we have setter for initialising "positions"
    public void Somefun (){
           int modifier [positions.length];
           // code for initialising "modifier"
           positions = modifier; 
    }
}
```

So my question is that when `Somefun` function returns then the portion of memory to which modifier is referencing will be eligible for garbage collection as modifier is destroyed.So does the statement

```
 positions = modifier;
```

makes sense as now to which area of memory `positions` is referencing?

Comment: Both the references will point to same object in memory. The reference is in `stack memory` not in `heap` and the actual object in in `heap memory`.

Comment: GC starts garbage collection from root, **not** from methods. As long as any single reference to memory location is accessible GC will **not** collect it.

Comment: The code you've given isn't valid. Did you mean `int[] modifier = new int[positions.length];`? It really helps if you post *actual* code rather than pseudo-code. (I'd also strongly advise you to follow the Java convention of keeping type information in one place, e.g. `private int[] positions` instead of `private int positions[]`.)

Comment: Why do you need to assign it in different local variable? Make it `final` so that it can be assigned at the time of object construction.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code will not compile (Java doesn't have static arrays). You instead need:

```
int[] modifier = new int[positions.length];
```

which creates a *new* block of memory on the heap for the `int` array and points `modifier` to it. Now when you do

```
positions = modifier;
```

`positions` is *also* pointed to that block of memory, and the block that `positions` *used* to point to can be garbage collected, assuming it isn't being referenced by another variable. It becomes easier to understand this if you think of all Java variables as pointers.

---

```
Initial
positions --------> (Allocated space 1)


int[] modifier = new int[positions.length];
positions --------> (Allocated space 1)
modifier  --------> (Allocated space 2)


positions = modifier;
                    (Allocated space 1)
positions --------> (Allocated space 2) <-------- modifier
```

Notice that now nothing is referencing *Allocated space 1*, so it can be freed by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common way for people to set and modify instance variables. The garbage collector will not pick up positions, but it will pick up the OLD address to which positions used to point.

Your code will still work as expected using this method.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to understand the references.

Here is the sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Dog d = new Dog();
    go(d);
}

public static void go(Dog dog){...}
```

Here `d` and `dog` both the references will point to the same `Dog` object in the `The Heap memory` and the references will reside in `The Stack memory` that will be destroyed once the scope of that method is finished.

[image]

---

> Is it safe to assign reference variable,which is of method level to Class level reference variable?

If you have the reference of any object then you are free to do anything with it. Try to avoid such type of assignment that might result in a bug in later stage of the application and it's very difficult to detect such type of bugs because you don't know which reference has changed the value.